# SQLite Database lock Mutli Query

Tags: c#, sqlite, unity-game-engine

Hello i have abit of a problem with my C# script basically it is supposed to run through a list array then update values on a sqlite database but it seems to lock up when trying to update the database this is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Parse;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class MyTestArray : MonoBehaviour {

    public int MyInt;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        int[] pets = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

        // ... Loop with the foreach keyword.
        foreach (int value in pets) {
            Debug.Log (value);

            MyInt = value;

            string sqlQuery;
            string conn = "";
            #if UNITY_EDITOR
            conn = "URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "DB.db";
            #elif UNITY_IPHONE

            conn = "URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "DB.db";
            #elif UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
            conn = "URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "DB.db";
            #elif UNITY_ANDROID
            conn = "URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "DB.db";
            #endif
            IDbConnection dbconn;
            dbconn = (IDbConnection)new SqliteConnection (conn);
            dbconn.Open (); //Open connection to the database.
            IDbCommand dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand ();
            PlayerPrefs.SetString ("Question", "1");

            sqlQuery = "select  SUM(qo.Score) from [Answer] as a inner join Questionas qo on a.Question= qo.QuestionI inner join Question as q on qo.QuestionId = q.QuestionId where q.QID=" + value;
            dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
            IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader ();
            while (reader.Read()) {
                int RiskNumber = reader.GetInt32 (0);
                Debug.Log (RiskNumber);
                string sqlQuery2 = "";
                string conn2 = "";
                #if UNITY_EDITOR
                conn2 = "URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "DB.db";
                #elif UNITY_IPHONE

                conn2 = "URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "DB.db";
                #elif UNITY_STANDALONE_WIN
                conn2 = "URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "DB.db";
                #elif UNITY_ANDROID
                conn2 = "URI=file:" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "DB.db";
                #endif
                IDbConnection dbconn2;
                dbconn2 = (IDbConnection)new SqliteConnection (conn2);
                dbconn2.Open (); //Open connection to the database.
                IDbCommand dbcmd2 = dbconn2.CreateCommand ();
                if (MyInt == 1){
                    sqlQuery2 = "UPDATE UserScore SET MyScore1="+RiskNumber;
                } else if (MyInt == 2){
                    sqlQuery2 = "UPDATE UserScore SET MyScore2="+RiskNumber;
                } else if (MyInt == 3){
                    sqlQuery2 = "UPDATE UserScore SET MyScore3="+RiskNumber;
                } else if (MyInt == 4){
                    sqlQuery2 = "UPDATE UserScore SET MyScore4="+RiskNumber;
                } else if (MyInt == 5){
                    sqlQuery2 = "UPDATE UserScore SET MyScore5="+RiskNumber;
                }

                Debug.Log (sqlQuery2);
                dbcmd2.CommandText = sqlQuery2;
                IDataReader reader2 = dbcmd2.ExecuteReader ();


                reader2.Close ();
                reader2 = null;
                dbcmd2.Dispose ();
                dbcmd2 = null;
                dbconn2.Close ();
                dbconn2 = null; 
            }




            reader.Close ();
            reader = null;
            dbcmd.Dispose ();
            dbcmd = null;
            dbconn.Close ();
            dbconn = null;  
        }   
    }

    }
```

Is it the way i am creating the query or have i missed something any help would be fantastic cheers

Comment: Why do you have opening connection in the loop? You need to open the connection to the database only once. You will have to dispose the existing connection before opening another one.

Comment: Could you show me what i could take out of my code to make it work better ? If you could that would be fantastic i think its just the connection but is there more i could remove. Cheers

Comment: You have an accepted answer. So I hope you have your problem solved. But still if I get some time I will add an answer with optimized code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh boy you really need to consider refactoring some of that code, not the best for performance either, however the problem is that you are opening another connection while still having the main connection open just reuse the same connection.

It happends in your while loop

Edit:
Noticing your code, it looks like you should be able to do a single sql query, by updating from select , hence no need for excessive looping